# show that $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx= \int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)dx$

Tags: calculus

I'm taking a second real analysis/calculus course and this identity showed up in one of my h.w assignments without proof and I'm trying to understand why it's true.

I was suggested to use the substitution $a-u=x$ but I don't see how that gets me anywhere.

This is not my h.w assignment so i'd just like to see a proof, I'm not looking for hints:

**show that if $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,a]$ then:**

$$\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx= \int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)dx$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: **HINT** Consider the substitution $a-u = x$

Comment: @gt6989b i don't get it, care to elaborate?
also, any idea why the downvotes?

Comment: Downvotes likely because people want to see what you tried and the context where you saw the problem... Here is a case in point. What happens when you try the substitution in my hint above? Where are you getting stuck on it?

Comment: @gt6989b
Thanks for explaining, I updated my question. should I open a new one because this one has been closed?
And I don't understand your substitution at all. I don't really get what your intention is to do with it so I can't specify what I don't understand. 
Would appreciate proof or guidance to full proof.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

We can establish a little more generic statement

$$\int_p^q f(x)\ dx=\int_p^q f(p+q-x)\ dx$$

Just replace $p+q-x$ with $y$