# Prove $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx= \int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I'm taking a second real analysis/calculus course and this identity showed up in one of my h.w assignments without proof and I'm trying to understand why it's true.

I was suggested to use the substitution $a-u=x$ but I don't see how that gets me anywhere.

This is not my h.w assignment so i'd just like to see a proof to understand why it's true, I'm not looking for hints:

**show that if $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,a]$ then:**

$$\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx= \int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)dx$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try substituting $u = a - x$ and re-arranging the limits? So $dx = -du$ and the limits change to $a$ and $0$ respectively. Try the limit reversal formula from there to get the above expression.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3636302/show-that-int-0afxdx-int-0afa-xdx

Comment: Mr. google is always with us to give such answers. https://byjus.com/maths/properties-of-definite-integral/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute: $u = a - x$

Then we have:

$$\int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)dx = \int_{a}^{0}f(u)d(a-u) =  \int_{a}^{0}f(u) \cdot (-1) \cdot d(u) = $$

$$ = - \int_{a}^{0}f(u)d(u) = \int_{0}^{a}f(u)d(u) = \int_{0}^{a}f(x)d(x)$$

In the last step we just did a formal replacement of the "letter" $u$ with $x$ (which we can always do).

Comment: thanks, how do we determine the "boundaries" of the integral after the first substitution? Is it enough to say that u=0 when x=a and u=a when x=0? is it always true if u is continuous?

Comment: I think it's only true when $u(x)$ is bijection. Continuous is not enough.